# How to set selected element by code using Select2?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I pass to Select2 component values in Json format, and than I want select one of values as  selected.

This is my code:

```
    $.getJSON(rootUrl+'getAllValues', {
        valu : $('#_valu_id').val()
    }, function(data) {

        var html = '<option value=""></option>';
        var len = data.length;

        for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if(data[i].myfield == $('#myfield').val()){
                html += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '" selected>'+ data[i].myfield + '</option>';
            }else{
                html += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">'+ data[i].myfield + '</option>';
            }
        }

        $('#_mySelect_id').html(html);

    });
```

But with only the `selected` attribute, it doesn't work.

**EDIT**: this is the `html` variable:

```
<option value=""></option>
<option value="30">U</option>
<option value="31">G</option>
<option value="32" selected="selected">A</option>
<option value="93">H</option>
```

So can I do it??

Thank in advance

Comment: The proper syntax would be selected="selected", but I don't think the problem lies there, but with the rest of your code. Try adding alert('a') in your if condition that should add "selected" to your option and make sure your code gets there.

Comment: I tried with selected="selected", but no changes. And yes, I try to add alert, and it step into in my if condition...

Comment: Can you inspect the resulting HTML that your code generates, and make sure that at least one "selected" option is in your select box? Also, alert your "html" variable after it has finished building and post it in your question please.

Comment: As far as I can see, this HTML code works as expected (check here: http://jsfiddle.net/9LvZR/). Try refreshing your page (CTRL+F5 for hard refresh) and make sure the rest of your code keeps their fingers off your select box.

Comment: I think that the problem is not in html, but in Select2, maybe with a function to refresh/reload the select2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you change the HTML contents of Select2, you have to update the selected value:

```
    function(data) {

        var html = '<option value=""></option>';
        var len = data.length;

        for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if(data[i].myfield == $('#myfield').val()){
                var selected_value = data[i].id; // Remember selected value
                html += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '" selected>'+ data[i].myfield + '</option>';
            }else{
                html += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">'+ data[i].myfield + '</option>';
            }
        }

        $('#_mySelect_id').html(html);

        $('#_mySelect_id').select2().select2('val',selected_value); // Update selected value
    }
```

Comment: I have another question.. Can I update it, without recall select2() costructor??

Comment: Feel free to try, since the element is already constructed, it might as well work.